# Refer to resource created by module TERRAFORM

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

got one question about terraform and reference to resource. Long story short: I have module to create AKS cluster (attachment) and I create cluster form one folder. On other folder I have other module to manage kubernetes it self: like create namespace, deployments etc. How can I refer to this cluster form other folder?[image]

Comment: You have to define outputs in the module whose values you need in the second module. But if you are not using it in the same root module, then you probably need something else.

Answer (score 0):

As Marko mentioned you would use outputs in the same root module, however if you are applying 1 plan, then the other you would likely need to use data sources.
Typically in my root modules I have a data-source.tf file with any pre-existing resources that I need to reference in the root module.

```
data "kubernetes_service" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "terraform-example"
  }
}
```

With the above data source defined, you can use it like this in your root module: `data.kubernetes_service.example.attribute-you-want-to-retrieve`

Here's a good reference: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/data-sources/service

Comment: Even though this is a correct answer I think you have it backwards: the question is how to reference the K8s cluster in the K8s module. :)

Comment: Good point @MarkoE & if 2 `terraform apply` cmds need to be run, the 2nd module will need to use a data source. @SanHolo if you need more clarification, let me know.

Comment: @paulg  So to clarify, I should add data source in one module, and then reference in second module to get this work?

Comment: @SanHolo A data source is a reference to a resource already created. Therefore, you add the data source in the 2nd module to reference the resource created in the 1st one. This is assuming the 2 modules are both root modules & run separately with terraform apply. If that's not the case then like Marko mentioned, you need to define outputs instead; https://www.terraform.io/language/values/outputs and https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references

Comment: @SanHolo if you provide your terraform config and how you're running it, we can assist better.